# If evaluation set is the same as training set, why would the evaluation error be different from training error?

Tags: categorical-encoding, catboost

I understand the use of evaluation set for parameter tuning and over-fitting in general. The examples in the evaluation set should be unseen and different from training set.

However, in the following toy CatBoost regression problem, in which I choose to set the evaluation to be identical with the training set, I do not understand why the evaluation error calculated deviate from the training error over iterations?

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor, Pool

cat_features = [0,]

train_data = [["b", 1,],
              ["b", 5,],
              ["e", 3,],
              ["c", 3,],
              ["d", 4,]]

train_labels = [1.,3.51, 0.43,0.45,0.55]
train_data = Pool(train_data, train_labels, cat_features=cat_features)
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=100, use_best_model=True, random_seed=1234)


model.fit(train_data, eval_set=train_data, verbose=True, plot=True)
```

The error rate for evaluation error (solid line) and training error (dotted line) over iterations are shown as follows:
[image]
On the other hand, if I choose to have change the only categorical feature to be a numerical feature (replacing a=1, b=2, c=3 and so on) as follows, the issue disappears, i.e., the evaluation error matches with the training error over all the iterations.

```
cat_features = []

train_data = [[2, 1,],
              [2, 5,],
              [5, 3,],
              [3, 3,],
              [4, 4,]]

train_labels = [1.,3.51, 0.43,0.45,0.55]
train_data = Pool(train_data, train_labels, cat_features=cat_features)
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=100, use_best_model=True, random_seed=1234)


model.fit(train_data, eval_set=train_data, verbose=True, plot=True)
```

I do not understand. I suspect this may be due to some randomness in categorical encoding. Could someone please help?

Comment: What exactly differs? You didn’t give us example of what you’re describing, so it’s unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the categorical encoding, yes; but it is not randomness.

CatBoost encodes its categoricals using a sliding target encoding.  During training, for each row, the value is the average target among rows *above* itself with the same level.  (There may be some smoothing or noise, but that's the general idea.)  But at prediction time, the encodings need to be fixed (you don't have a target anymore): they are the global target encoding from the training set.

Your training scores are using the special catboost-encoding, while the evaluation scores are using the global target encoding.